# CSS First Child Not Working

Tags: css

I am trying to have 3 elements space 76 pixels apart (except for the first element) within a div that is centered. However, the first-child pseudo-class doesn't seem to wanna enforce itself. It keeps getting overridden by the original rule.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kesr6vsr/)

### CSS

```
.buddy-icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .buddy-oval-icon {
    padding-left: 76px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
  }
  .buddy-icons > [class^="buddy-oval-icon"]:first-child {
    padding-left: none;
  }
```

Comment: If none of the answers helped or you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Answer (score 0):

`none` is an invalid value for `padding-left`. Use `0` instead

```css
.buddy-icons {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.buddy-oval-icon {
  padding-left: 76px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
.buddy-icons > [class^="buddy-oval-icon"]:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="buddy-icons">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/button_blank_red_100846.jpg" class="buddy-oval-icon">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/button_blank_red_100846.jpg" class="buddy-oval-icon">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/button_blank_red_100846.jpg" class="buddy-oval-icon">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
.buddy-icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
 .buddy-oval-icon {
    padding-left: 76px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
  }
  .buddy-oval-icon:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
```

**<kbd>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kesr6vsr/1/)</kbd>**

Comment: what about centering the .buddy-icons class?

Comment: In this case, you can use `text-align:center;`. There are only images, with text-align all work fine. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/kesr6vsr/4/

Answer (score 0):

use `padding-left: 0;` for `.buddy-icons > [class^="buddy-oval-icon"]:first-child`

```css
.buddy-icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.buddy-oval-icon {
    padding-left: 76px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
.buddy-icons >[class^="buddy-oval-icon"]:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="buddy-icons">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/button_blank_red_100846.jpg" class="buddy-oval-icon">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/button_blank_red_100846.jpg" class="buddy-oval-icon">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/button_blank_red_100846.jpg" class="buddy-oval-icon">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the following in your code, worked for me in your fiddle.

```
.buddy-icons > [class^="buddy-oval-icon"]:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add spacing between two objects by adding margin on its sides. The CSS code is as follows,

```
.element_name{
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

to add space on left side or you can add space on right side by using the following code,

```
.element_name{
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.buddy-icons {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .buddy-oval-icon {
        padding-left: 76px;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
      }
      .buddy-oval-icon:nth-of-type(1) {
        padding-left: 0px;
      }
```